# bypass pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a python application that requires a package that uses newrelic. I want to test my application with a newer version of newrelic, but the package has a max version on newrelic which is lower then the one I want to test out.

So before I update the package to use the newer version of newrelic I want to test it out. But I get a pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound when I start my application with the newer newrelic version.

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'newrelic<3dev,>=2.88.1.73' distribution was not found and is required by xxxx
```

Is there a way to bypass this requirement by the package?

If so - how?

Or if there is an even easier way I just haven't thought of.